# How to convert non-standard lognormal data to normal (scipy)?

Tags: lognormal-distribution, scipy

I want to transform some data points, which I assume follow an unknown non-standard lognormal distribution, to follow a normal distribution.

When I fit the data with a lognormal distribution using [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html), I get a non-zero value for the loc parameter (shift).

So I use the following procedure:

1. I fit a lognormal distribution to my data to find the value of the shift parameter (loc)
2. I shift the data: data - loc
3. I compute the natural logarithm of the data

In code the procedure is the following:

```py
data = ... # pandas series
shape, loc, scale = lognorm.fit(data) # fit the data
data = data.apply(lambda x: np.log(x - loc)) # shift and apply logarithm
```

In some answers, such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/296843/379568),they just say to take the logarithm of the data, and do not address a possible shift.

In my case this would be possible because the data is shifted to the right, so values are all positive, but would I obtain normally distributed data? I think that, depending from the shift, the transformed data would deviate from normality. Am I wrong?

To summarize these are my questions:

- is my procedure correct?
- If I don't shift the data, to save on the computational complexity of fitting the distribution (in my application this is important), do I introduce an error (deviation from normality)? If yes, can I quantify it in some way?

Comment: This seems mainly a question of terminology.  What most people mean by "lognormal" is a random variable whose logarithm has a Normal distribution: that corresponds to the formula in the scipy docs.  *Sometimes* a *generalized* or *three-parameter* lognormal is meant in which a lognormal random variable has been (additively) translated, as here.   That corresponds to the optional `loc` argument in the scipy implementation *which is not reflected in the formula there.* As a rule you should *not* assume this is what someone means when referring to "lognormal" unless they have stated otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a log-normal distribution is that taking the log gives a normal distribution.

$$
X\sim\text{log-normal}$$$$
\Bigg\Updownarrow$$$$
\log\left(
X
\right)\sim\text{Normal}
$$

If you believe the first distribution to be log-normal, just take the logarithm to get a normal distribution.

If there is a shift $k$ from the standard location of a log-normal distribution, then subtracting $k$ would happen before the logarithm, with the resulting distribution being normal. If you do not know this shift, however, then its estimation is subject to error, and $\log\left(X-\hat k\right)$ might not be quite the right transformation to give a normal distribution. For instance, if you have $k=2$ but $\hat k = 2.1$, then you subtract the wrong location shift. This will be particularly problematic if $\hat k\ge X_{(1)}$ (that is, if the estimated location shift is greater than or equal to the smallest observed value (first order statistics)), as that will result in taking the logarithm of a value $\le 0$.

Comment: Ok, but according to the fit, my random variable is $X$ ~ lognormal + K,  so I'm not sure that $log(X)$ ~ Normal holds.