How to make two perfectly negatively correlated growing Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) series? (Impossibility)
Intro
I am self studying in Youtube the course MIT 18.S096 Topics in Mathematics w Applications in Finances and in the following lecture min 34:50 by Dr. Jake Xia is studied the efficient frontier of a portfolio made by two assets with with expected returns $R_1 = R_2$ and variances $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$, where a portfolio is made using a weights $w_1$ and $w_2$ such is return is given by $R_p = w_1R_1+w_2R_2$ with variance $\sigma_p^2 = w_1^2\sigma_1^2+w_2^2\sigma_2^2+2\rho_{12}w_1w_2\sigma_1\sigma_2$, in this case $w_2=1-w_1$ since only two assets are considered:
In this specific section of the lecture is studied the case of perfectly negatively correlated assets $\rho_{12}=-1$ telling that in this magic case all the risk could eliminated for having  the return $R=R_p=R_1=R_2$, which makes sense from the formulas, but I got suspicious if this scenario is compatible with modeling assets through the Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) series (which are introduced later on the lectures):
Let think that both assets $S_1(t)$ and $S_2(t)$ follows each one a classic GBM series:
$$S_1(t) = S_{01}\exp\left(\left(\mu_1-\dfrac{v_1^2}{2}\right)t+v_1W_{1t}\right)$$
$$S_2(t) = S_{02}\exp\left(\left(\mu_2-\dfrac{v_2^2}{2}\right)t+v_2W_{2t}\right)$$
such the processes $W_{1t}$ and $W_{2t}$ are individual Wiener Processes that distributes normally $\sim N(0,t)$, but each GBM process is such as is growing in time/tendency so they fulfill that $\mu_i-\dfrac{v_i^2}{2}>0$. I have change the Wikipedia notation of the standard deviations on the exponentials from sigma to $v_i$ so I don't get confused with the portfolio variances from the first paragraph.
Question
Is it possible to make a perfectly negatively correlated scenario such the mentioned in the video using $S_1$ and $S_2$? How their parameters are going to be related? (Use please $S_1$ as the reference)... My intuition tells me that growing processes should have always some kind of positive correlation so the mentioned scenario sounds to me as a lie.
Please consider to explain the formulas you use for taking the Expected Returns and Variances for the portfolios using the two GBM assets as you build them, since I got into trouble by making them by myself (this is why I couldn't answer this by my own). In the case is not possible, please consider to deliver you answer as a demonstration of that fact.

If $\rho = -1$, then two assets are perfectly negatively correlated. But the $\rho$ is an element of the covariance matrix of the two brownian motions so $\rho$ can be anything you want as long as the brownian motions are generated accordingly. As far as the trend, they don't add correlation but, if you don't remove them from the generated series, you're going to have problems doing any type of statistical-time series analysis. The trend causes SERIOUS problems for any statistical procedure but it doesn't create correlated series in the usual sense of correlation.

If you want to learn more rigorously about the problem with trends, this is the classical paper that was a real breakthrough at the time.  https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Spurious-regressions-in-econometrics-Granger-Newbold/b95bf0c31332005d2d2ca918f3e1fe59fb998839

@markleeds thanks for the paper. I don't see though, how it would change the problem, at least as presented on the videos, the solutions should be very obvious, but instead, I even have problems finding in Google how to properly calculate the Expected Return of a GBM, when it should just be $E[d\ln(S_t)]$ and the variance $V[d\ln(S_t)]$, but myself I get in trouble with Ito's calculations (I am very rookie in this)... Do you know some source where these are calculated?

@KurtG. we will see... I think I have already solve it and as much the will always with less than $\rho<-0.4$ if the expected return are the same. I would try to upload my attempt next Monday (I have to work this weekend)

@KurtG. I have just realized that I have translated wrong what I were asking, so your answer makes sense now, My apologies in advance. As mentioned in the question I am asking about the cases $\rho=-1$ and I named it as perfectly uncorrelated when it should have been perfectly negatively correlated so now I corrected accordingly.

Joako: I'm not clear on the question ? If you're trying to get rid of the risk in the brownian motion components, then, as Kurt said, you can use the negative of the brownian motion in the other relations which will make the 2 brownian motions perfectly negatively correlated so that their effects will cancel. I'm not sure if that's your question because you mentioned the trends also. The trends will be problematic in terms of any time-series analysis but maybe you are not dealing with that issue.

@markleeds I will upload my attempt, I think there it would become crystal clear. I will ping you when I am done with the upload.

@markleeds I have done with the analysis, if you still have doubts I recommend you to check the lecture I shared where the example I took is explained.

@KurtG. I think I will keep my first opinion so far nobody else show me where my analysis is mistaken

@mlofton I have done with the analysis, if you still have doubts I recommend you to check the lecture I shared where the example I took is explained.

Thanks for the detailed write up but I haven't read it yet. I look forward to reading it and I don't expect to find any problems.

Sorry, but any thread in which the "Question" overflows into an "Answer" does not to me qualify as a focused thread. IMO, this doesn't work well as a contribution to CV, despite the interest and massive effort  it has received.

@NickCox I don't understand your comment: the question have been kept as it was originally made (was made on MSE by the way). The overflow were my attempts trying to answer it, veryfing the results. I cannot fight against policies and if it was interesting for others well is not my fault they would not see it now, I just fulfill with moderators requirements. But since the question is not deleted (finally), they could check the edit history to see them. I am just grateful I didn't lost it (I have save it now on a text document), the develop was very helpful for my own understanding.

If anyone has a good question here, they should be able to ask it fairly concisely. If anyone wants to write a paper, there are, or should be, better places to publish (= make that public).  That view is I think entirely consistent with the original reasons for closure, which to my mind have not been resolved,  You want your writing to be allowed as an exception to good practice here and all precedents of length and focus. I can't support that, but I have (fortunately) only one voice and one vote.  I am happy that you found the exercise helpful, but that's not a criterion here.

@NickCox So you aim to have only questions done by people who knows the answer? kind of show offs?... well I asked trying to understand, sorry if I am not a genious, which I have never claimed. And there is a voting system developed to downgrade questions you dislike.

Not at all. It is not out of order to ask a question you know the answer to, but almost always a question is asked because you don't know an answer. That's standard, and nothing to do with my comments. The quality of your work is not material either; it's entirely to me a matter of what works well on CV. (Thanks for reminding me about voting, with which I am familiar)

@NickCox well, I matter about trying to understand why a world's top university is teaching through top executives of one of the most prestigious investment banks in the world how to manage funds with a model that it is inaccurate.... but I am just an electrician, so sometimes is harder to me to understand.

It is interesting to know why you are interested in the question, but that doesn't address my concerns at all.

For geometric Brownian motion the return is log normal distributed, and you can not have negatively correlated log normal distributed variables. Namely, this would require $(Y-\bar{Y}) = -(X-\bar{X})$, but mirroring a log normal distributed variable does not result in another log normal distributed variable.
For small time steps the return becomes approximately a linear function of the Wiener process
$$e^{a+b(W_{t+\Delta t}-W_{t})} \approx e^a  \left[1+\frac{b}{a}(W_{t+\Delta t}-W_{t}) \right]$$
and if you have two series with opposite noise terms $(W_{1,t+\Delta t}-W_{1,t}) = -(W_{2,t+\Delta t}-W_{2,t})$ then you can make a sum such that approximately the risk/noise terms cancel.

Alternatively, for a bivariate normal distribution $X_1,X_2$, with means and deviation $\mu_i,\sigma_i$, you can compute the correlation of  $Y_1=e^{X_1},Y_2=e^{X_2}$ using the approach in Expectation, Variance and Correlation of a bivariate Lognormal distribution

Relating to that alternative: $$\rho(Y_1,Y_2) = \frac{Cov(Y_1,Y_2)}{\sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{Y_2}}  $$
Filling in the result from Glen_b's answer $$Cov(Y_1,Y_2) =E[Y_1]E[Y_2] \left( e^{ Cov[X_1,X_2]}-1 \right)$$ and filling in $$\sigma_{Y_i} = E[Y_i]\sqrt{e^{\sigma_i^2}-1}$$, we get
$$\rho(Y_1,Y_2) =  \frac{ e^{ Cov[X_1,X_2]}-1}{\sqrt{e^{Var(Y_1)}-1} \sqrt{e^{Var(Y_2)}-1} } = \frac{ e^{ \rho(X_1,X_2)}-e^{-\sigma_1\sigma_2}}{\sqrt{(1-e^{-\sigma_{1}^2}}\sqrt{1-e^{-\sigma_2^2}} }  $$ I am not sure how to continue.

thanks for the answer. Let me see if I am following you: the second part of your analysis is about how making two series with noises $W_{2t}=-W_{1t}$ leads to uncorrelated processes $\rho\approx 0$ instead of perfectly negatively correlated $\rho=-1$ processes, right?

about the comment on the bivariate Lognormal analysis, I saw them with caution: given is true GBM distributes Lognornally, Lognormal distributions could be ergodic but GBM is not, given the term proportional to time that accompanies $\sigma^2$, and I am not sure if traditional LogNormal distrib. analysis are aware of this issue with GBMs

I have added now a simulation analysis and I have found that the correlation coefficient between GBM series is not just $\rho[S_1,S_2]\neq 1$, but much worst, as time passes the series start increase its correlation coefficient passing zero to becoming highly correlated. I don't know I missed something but for the efficient frontier analysis assumptions is like a worst case scenario. Hope you could take a look, I left the code at the end.

@Joako I don't follow the expression auxS = corrcoef(GBM1(1:1:ceil(length/10),m),GBM2(1:1:ceil(length/10),m)); the octave vector indices are unknown to me. Also, is this the brownian motion or the returns that you are computing the correlation for?

those are the correlation coefficients for the GBM series $S_1$ and $S_2$ , so $\rho[S_1,S_2]$ but for the first samples and not the entire time, let say if the entire series ends at time $t_2$, the shown in your comment considers only the string up to time $t_1<t_2$ (in this case, up to the time coincident with the length of the string of samples divided by ten)

I think that the small time step return won't going to work for the portfolio: let name $x=\ln(w_1)+\ln(S_1)$ and  $y=\ln(w_2)+\ln(S_2)$ then the portfolio is $P_t=e^x+e^y$ and finding it log-return becomes $$\ln(P_r) = \ln(e^x+e^y) \approx \frac{x\ e^{\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}-y\ e^{\frac{y}{\ln(2)}}}{e^{\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}-e^{\frac{y}{\ln(2)}}} \neq \ln(e^x) +\ln(e^y) = x + y$$ the mix is highly nonlinear so I think the first order Taylor expansion won't be accurate. By the way, the approximation for splitting the logarithm of a sum I found it here

@Joako of course the geometric series will be positively correlated if they have the same drift (also with regular Brownian motion plus drift), but wasn't the question about the correlation of the returns? You will get a different answer when you compute a series of returns , then compute the correlation.

That is not what I found: in Eq. 16 where the correlation coefficients of the GBM series is found the drifts are not involved at all (against my initial intuition), even though, they aren't considered in the formula you shared on the comments $\rho[Y_1,Y_2]$, so is not obvious for me. Please elaborate on this.

@Joako I consider the $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to be the returns, and not the series itself.

I see. It makes math sense as Arithmetic Brownian motion (ABM) or GBM with very low parameters (like $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2\approx 0$ since behaves almost ABM), but since portfolios are made as $P_t = w_1S_1+w_2S_2$ and not $Pt=w_1Y_1+w_2Y_2$ it makes no practical sense. Its like Markowitz's efficient frontier was designed for a problem it don't apply, since prices are cumulative in its strict discrete nature $S_i = \Pi_{k=1}^N (1+r_k)$ with $r_k$ its returns on each discrete time interval: they saw an chess board and made the most optimal strategy for chess, too bad the game was checkers :(

@Joako still, you should compute the correlation in returns $R$ and not the series $S$. Your simulation will just as well 'fail' for ABM and it has nothing to do with GBM.

For me doing the variance analysis on the returns when I am buying the assets that follows a process that it is not ergodic makes little sense (I tried to understand that here), and for me doing something like this requires less assumptions.

@Joako you have written so much that it starts to get confusing . I am just considering your definitions for GBM $$S_1(t) = S_{01}\exp\left(\left(\mu_1-\dfrac{v_1^2}{2}\right)t+v_1W_{1t}\right) $$ and the returns. $$R_{\Delta t}:=\dfrac{S_{t+\Delta t}-S_t}{S_t}=\dfrac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}-1 \iff 1+R_{\Delta t}=\dfrac{S_{t+\Delta t}}{S_t}$$ Here the variance formula of a combined portfolio still works, and we can have a negative correlation in the returns (but not exactly -1).

Do you think your initial answer linearization is equivalent to what I did here?

Hi Joako: I read through all of your derivations and it's all well done.
I think you may just be slightly (not much) not understanding the meanings of some of the terms. You have below.
$$\sigma_p^2 = w_1^2V[S_1]+w_2^2V[S_2]+2\rho_{12}^*w_1w_2\sqrt{V[S_1]V[S_2]}\tag{Eq. 8}$$
Notice that the $V[S_1]$ and $V[S_2]$ denote the two variances of the two brownian motions, so they are $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$. From reading your explanation, tt was not clear to me whether you knew that or not. There is no other variation in the portfolio except for the variances due to the brownian motions. You can't get rid of them no matter what the lecturer may have said.
The $\sigma_p^2$ is the variance of the returns of the portfolio if the two stocks, $S_1$ and $S_2$ were held with weights $w_1$ and $w_2$. So, to emphasize,  it is NOT POSSIBLE to eliminate the first two terms. They are all positive and can't be cancelled out. The only thing one can do is minimize the overall variance of the portfolio, $\sigma_p^2$.
How can one do this ? Take the last term. That can be made smallest by somehow making $\rho_{12}$ of the stocks equal to -1.0 .
Now, notice that, later on in your well done explanation, you have this:
$$\Rightarrow \boxed{\rho_{12}^*  =  \dfrac{e^{v_1v_2t\rho_w(t)}-1}{\sqrt{(e^{v_1^2t}-1)(e^{v_2^2t}-1)}}} \tag{Eq.16}$$
Now, if you somehow make $v_1 = v_2$ and $\rho_w(t) = -1$ then
$\rho_{12}$ will be -1.0.
So the question comes down to: "How can one construct the brownian
motions so that $v_1 = v_2$ and $\rho_{12} = -1.0$ ?".
Well, we can construct one brownian motion with whatever variance we want, say $v_1$. Call this process $W_1$.
Next suppose, we construct the other brownian motion to be $-W_{1}$
and call this $W_2$. Now, the portfolio variance becomes:
$$\sigma_p^2 = w_1^2 V[S_1]+ w_2^2 V[S_1]+ 2 \times -1.0 ^*w_1 \times w_{2}\sqrt{V[S_1]V[S_1]}$$.
Besides choosing the values of $w_1$ and $w_2$ ( use the expression immediately above for this ), there is nothing else you can do to make the portfolio variance above smaller. I hope this helps.
P.S.: Notice that the choice of $w_1$ and $w_2$ will effect the variance so, in addition to making $W_2 = -W_1$,
a useful exercise is to figure out what those weights, $w_1$ and $w_2$ should be  to insure that the portfolio variance is as small as possible.
I hope this helped some.
UPDATE: ML: 10-14-2024
#==============================================================
joako: In thinking about this a little more, the case where one is allowed to hold the opposite of $W_1$ in the second process is somewhat unorthodox and causes the portfolio variance formula to blow up ( i.e. it's not correct ).
But, I figured out a modified formula that fixes this issue. I'll explain it here.
Suppose, we denote the weight of the $W_1$ process as $w_1$.
Also, let us denote the weight of the $W_2$ process that is in $-1.0 W_1$ as $w_{s}$. Finally, denote the weight of the $W_2$ process that
is NOT in $-1.0 W_1$ as $w_{2}$. So, by definition, $w_{1} + w_{2} = 1.0$. Also, there is an additional constraint which is that $w_s$ can only be as large as $w_1$.
So, suppose for example that that we hold $2/3$ of the portfolio in $W_1$ and $1/6$ of the portfolio in $-1.0 \times W_{1}$, and 1/3 of the portfolio in the regular $W_2$ process.
Given these weights,  then, denote the corrected weight of $W_1$, denoted as
$$wc_{1} = (w_1-w_s) = 2/3 - 1/6 = 3/6$$
and the corrected weight of $W_2$, denoted as
$$wc_{2} = w_2/(wc_1 + w_2) = 2/6/(3/6 + 2/6) = 4/10$$.
The weight denoting how much is put in the $-1.0 W_1$ process is still $w_s = 1/6$.
Note that the formula for correcting the weights is such that the corrected weights, $wc_1$ and $wc_2$, do not sum to 1.0 which means the rest of the portfolio is in cash . It is implicitly assumed that leaving part of the investment in cash causes no variance.
Finally, using these corrected weight formulae, the formula for the portfolio variance becomes (wc denotes weight corrected ).
$$\sigma_p^2 = wc_1^2 V[S_1] +  wc_2^2
V[S_2]+  2\rho_{12} wc_1 wc_2 \sqrt{V[S_1]V[S_2]}$$
Notice that when $w_2 = 0.0 $ and , $w_s$, the weight of the $-1.0 W_{1}$ component process, equals $ w_{1} = 1.0 $, then the portfolio variance now becomes zero as it should.
So my only point to the update is that, IF one is allowed to use some amount of weight, $w_{s}$, of the second process as $-1.0 \times W_{1}$, then the modified portfolio variance formula above should be used.
#=============================================================
.
UPDATE: ML: 10-22-2024
#==============================================================
joako:  Here is the R code which shows what I was trying to say
about the random component. I hope it helps you see that it cancels.
THIS R CODE SHOWS THAT,
IF YOU INVEST IN 1/2 OF YOUR TOTAL DOLLARS IN S1 AND
AND HALF OF YOUR DOLLARS IN S2 AND S1 AND S2 HAVE THE OPPOSITE
BUT IDENTICAL RANDOM RETURN COMPONENTS,
THEN THE ONLY TOTAL RETURN ONE RECEIVES IS THE SUM OF THE
WEIGHTED COMBINATION OF THE TWO DRIFT COMPONENTS. THE RANDOM
RETURN COMPONENT IS ZERO AS EXPECTED

INITIALIZATION SECTION

set.seed(1)
S1orig <- 100.00
S2orig <- 50.00
sigma1 <- 1.0
mu1<- 1.0
v1 <- 1.0
mu2 <- mu1
sigma2  <- sigma1
tbegin <- 1
tend <- 100
totrandret <- 0.0
totS1drift <- 0.0
totS2drift <- 0.0
totS1randret <- 0.0
totS2randret <- 0.0

SECTION WHERE WE
LOOP THROUGH 100 DAYS 
AND UPDATE EVERYTHING ACCORDINGLY
THIS WAY WE KEEP TRACK OF DRIFT COMPONENT
AND RANDOM COMPONENT AS THEY CHANGE
OVER TIME

for (i in ((tbegin+1):tend)) {   
  S1randret  <- sigma1 * rnorm(0,0.001)
  S2randret  <- -1.0 * S1randret
  totS1randret <- totrandret + totS1randret
  totS2randret <- totrandret + totS2randret    
  totrandret <- totS1randret + totS2randret        
  S1drift <-  (mu1 - v1^2/2)
  totS1drift <- totS1drift + S1drift    
  S2drift <-  S1drift
  totS2drift <- totS2drift + S2drift                      
}

AFTER LOOPING, CALC TOTAL DRIFT
AND TOTAL RANDOM COMPONENTS

totdrift <- (1/2 * totS1drift) + (1/2 * totS2drift)
totdrift

totret <- totdrift + totrandret      
totret

THEY ARE EQUAL WHICH MEANS totret IS COMPOSED ONLY
OF totdrift AND totrandret EQUALS ZERO

all.equal(totret,totdrift)


.
ML: 10-24-2024 ANOTHER ADDENDUM BASED ON NEW COMMENTS FROM JOAKO
#===================================================================
Hi Joako: I will address a couple of different issues and number them as I go.

Consider equation 16), where you have the formula for the autocorrelation. In my comments about that equation, said that we need $\rho_w$ to be perfectly correlated with a correlation of -1.
Correlation measures linear association so, in theory, two brownian motions could be perfectly correlated where one moves -1/2 the amount that the other moves. That correlation would still be -1.0.  Therefore, using the term correlated with a perfect correlation of -1.0 is ambiguous. I should have said that the two brownian motions have to be identical and opposite which results in a correlation between the two brownian motion returns of -1.  What this implies about the resulting correlation on the prices  depends on whether one is referring to log prices or prices but that's a different issue which I address later.

I read through  your derivations and comments and I didn't understand your comments exactly but I could sense that you found some inconsistencies between GBM and the Markowitz formulation. As far as this goes, all I can say is that Markowitz was TOTALLY not concerned with the practical issues of how to compute the returns and covariances that went into his formulation.  All of the BM-GBM stuff was developed after his formulation. So, if something is not consistent, it's not Harry's fault !!!! He didn't care if your forecasts were off the top of your head and the covariances were
picked from a hat. His only interest and goal was a quantitative formulation of how to calculate portfolio risk and return.


I couldn't tell what the inconsistency was but GBM does not have symmetric risk like arithmetic returns have. Therefore, there could be inconsistencies between GBM and the Markowitz setup but, generally speaking, no one uses the returns to calculate the markowitz covariance matrix anyway. The covariance matrix is usually constructed through the use of some kind of factor model. Again, I'm not sure what problems you had so I could be barking up the wrong tree as far as Markowitz and why arithmetic returns are a problem.

I was wondering why you kept having all these complicated equations and were using $exp$ in many places when calculating the return. Eventually, I realized what was going on:

We have a geometric brownian model which says that the difference in log prices is the sum of 1) a drift of $\mu$ and 2) a return component which is brownian motion scaled by some volatility.
By making this assumption, one is implicitly assuming that the price has a drift $\mu$ - \sigma^2/2$ term because the underlying model is geometric brownian motion.
So, therefore when calculating the arithmetic return under the assumption that the model for prices is geometric brownian motion, an inconsistency is being introduced.  Something is wrong because both models can't hold at the same time: The expected value of the price can't be $\mu$ ( which is what it is when using arithmetic returns ) and $\mu - \sigma^2/2$ at the same time.
So, my point is that geometric brownian motion implies that, for $S$, the variance component gets subtracted from the drift term. Therefore, one cannot calculate arithmetic returns using the geometric brownian motion model. Does that make sense ? There is an underlying model implied when one uses arithmetic returns and it's standard brownian motion. (I'll try to find something that shows this.). Therefore, calculating arithmetic returns assuming a GBM means that arithmetic returns can't be normally distributed or that log differences can't be normally distributed. Both can't be true at the same time.
So, in summary, if you really want to use arithmetic returns, then you have to use the brownian motion model and this model has problems because, under BM, prices can become negative. This is why GBM was invented. I think it was Bachelier in 1906 who came up with the idea of using BM for stock prices.

As far as what's going on with that term that gets subtracted
from the drift component, there's something called "variance drain"
when one calculates log returns. It's the idea that geometric returns
are not symmetric. For example,  suppose some stock price is 10 dollars. Then a 50 percent decrease requites a 100 percent increase to get back to the same 10 dollars. So, a stock price can drag when using geometric returns. Google for "variance drain" if you're interested in this topic.  Or even better, "Becker variance drain". I remember reading a good paper of his. If you want it and can't find it, let me know.

IMHO, it's best to assume geometric brownian motion and, in that case, log price differences are assumed normally distributed and the returns are additive over time. Using arithmetic returns won't kill you but, mathematically, it's inconsistent with GBM and you can't add them over time. Additive returns can offer some advantages when modelling.

Oh, one more thing. Note that the idea of using $W_2 = -1.0 W_1$ is pretty unrealistic in practice because, if one was going to do that with some stock say IBM, then it would be just as easy to not hold IBM in any positive weight (don't hold it at all) so that the portfolio risk was zero. By thinking of $-1.0 W_1$ as another equity position, one runs into the problem of how to write out the portfolio variance because the standard portfolio variance always assumes that whatever is held short is also not held long and vice versa. This is why I had to use that strange approach where I introduced another weight called $w_s$. It's never really necessary to do that because, in practice, one would never hold two opposite and identical positions. They don't get you anything. The drift I guess can be thought of as some theoretical risk premium for being invested in the stock market but you don't need two opposite and identical positions to get exposed to a risk premium.

So, that's pretty much all I can say.
I don't know much these comments helped but, assuming you have any more questions, it's probably best to start a new question rather than adding to this thread because it kind of became a book rather than a thread !!!!!!!! LOL. And Thanks a lot for your help with MathJax or whatever it's called. Do you know where the tutorial is. Someone was kind enough to edit some old thread of mine and provide the link to the tutorial and now I can't remember what the thread was.
ML: 10-24-2024 ANOTHER ADDENDUM FOR ARITHMETIC RETURNS IMPLYING BM.
#==============================================================
Joako: For brownian motion, one has
(1) ( leaving out the t subscripts for a moment )
$$ ds = \mu dt + \sigma W $$
So, one can think of $ds$ as representing a small price change.
Therefore,  based on (1), price changes are normally distributed
because, discretizing, results in:
$$ S_{t+1} - S_{t} = \mu + \sigma W_{t+1} $$
One could say, well, yeah there's a brownian motion in above but how does that imply arithmetic returns ? There's nothing in the denominator and price changes are not returns !!!!!!!
Answer: Arithmetic return is defined as the price change divided by the original price But, one can think of the original price (S_t) as a scaling factor that is already known and does not affect the distribution of the price change. Therefore, price changes being normal (i.e: brownian ) is the same as arithmetic returns being normal
( i.e: brownian ).
I hope this helps to see why you're calculating arithmetic returns under the GBM assumption leads to an incosistentcy. People might do this or you my have seen it in the literature but I haven't seen it done andf the inconsistency is most likely the reason why.
Also, I took a quick glance at Becker's paper and now I don't think it's related to what you're getting at. But, I could be wrong so it's still worth taking a quick glance at. All the best.

Thanks for reviewing my calculations and taking the time to answer. About my confusion, I do think there are 3 variances: let say we have a GBM process given by $$S_3=S_0\exp((\mu-\sigma_3^2/2)t+\sigma_3W_t)$$ then you will have the variance $$V[S_3]=S_0^2\exp(2\mu t)(\exp(\sigma_3^2t)-1)$$ also the variance of the Wiener process $W_t\sim N(0,t)$ given by $$\sigma_w=\sqrt{t}\Rightarrow \sigma_3^2 = t$$ and the term $\sigma_3^2$ itself which is the ponderator of the variance of the Brownian motion $B_t\sim N(0,\sigma_3^2t)$ and that its different from $\sigma_3\neq V[S_3]$. (...)

(...) and my problem was I was already using sigmas from the analysis at the beginning as the lecture do, where they will have made a confussion with the terms on the GBM exponentials, so I defined instead using $v_3:=\sigma_3$ from the comments example, and $V[S_3]$ those who went jointly with weight $w_3$ in this case

Hi Joako: you have $S_3 = S_{0}exp((u-\sigma_{3}^2/2)t + \sigma_{3} W_{t})$. The only random variable in that expression is $W_t$. It's brownian motion. You are making a log normal transformation which makes the expression maybe look like there are other variances but there aren't. $\sigma^2_3$ is just a scale factor multiplying the brownian motion because it's standardized and it needs to be un-standardized. Since it's a scale factor for the standardized BM, one can think of $\sigma_3^2$ as the variance of the associated brownian motion.

sorry in my first comment was $$B_t=\sigma_3W_t\sim N(0,\sigma_3^2t)$$

Joako: Maybe check out a reference or document for transformation to log normal random variables. Then you may see it more clearly. I'll try to find one. Basically, they have a normal rv and they need to get rid of the exponentiation so they take the log but this converts the variable to a log normal which makes the variance look a little strange. Same for the mean.

Yes, in your correction you are showing what I was referring to as a scale factor. The ONLY rv in your fcomment above is $W_t$. $\sigma_3$ is a parameter so a constant. It comes into play in the variance but it's not adding any variation to the process. The only things that do that are the random variables, in this case $W_t$.

Just to be clear: $\sigma^2_3 \times t$ is the variance of the random variable $W_t$. Think of it like this: I have a standardized normal random variable  $Z \sim N(0,1)$. What's the variance of $\sigma Z$ ? It's $\sigma^2$ but the variation is still due to $Z$ being a random variable. $\sigma^2$ is a constant.

I use it because as difference since I was not sure if when taking the variance of $$V[v_1W_{1t}+v_2W_{2t}]$$ I should be using $\rho$ associated to $B_t$ or to $W_t$ so it keep me sane with the constants

No problem. If you have any questions about anything, just ask or start a new thread. You understand most of the material but knowing what has variance and what does not is key. The only random variables in your problem are $W_1$ and $W_2$. This might help with conversion to log normal which is really what you're doing. Look at whuber's answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265785/how-can-i-convert-a-lognormal-distribution-into-a-normal-distribution

$\rho$ is the correlation of the two lognormal processes ( which exists because of the two brownian motions which are normal ). As Kurt  said originally, by setting $W_2 = -W_{1}$ we can make $\rho = -1.0$ which you're formula nicely showed. But that's all we can do to minimize $\sigma_{p}^2$. There is no other variation.  Although choosing the values of $w_1$ and $w_2$ can help also.

joako: I'm gonna log out now but, if you have any questions or confusions, just ask. I suggest you remove your question in cross-validated because it's there also but it doesn't have exactly the same content. All the best.

mmm.... what I think I proved is the opposite, that is impossible to have $\rho=-1$ even when $W_2=W_1$

For $\rho$ to equal -1,0,  one needs $W_{2} = -1.0 \times W_{1}$. So, whatever values $W_1$ takes on, $W_2$ will take the opposite. Just calculate corr(W_{1}, -W_{1}).

I made a mistake about cross-validated thread. I thought we were on math.stackexchange but we weren't, my mistake to say that you should delete this thread.

If the portfolio variance is $$\sigma_p^2 = w_1^2V[S_1]+w_2^2V[S_2] + 2w_1w_2\sqrt{V[S_1]V[S_2]}\rho[S_1,S_2]$$ then when $W_2=-W_1$ it will make $\rho[W_1,W_2]=-1$ but the parameter I am talking $\rho[S_1,S_2]>-1$ always for $t>0$ and parameters of the GBM $\sigma_1>0$ and $\sigma_2>0$ (maybe I should have use this notation on the question to begin with)

joako: I'm going to mdify the portfolio variance equation because it's not correct when one is allowed to set W_{2} to some negative part of $W_1$.  The portfolio variance equation, as it currently stands, only allows for positive weightings.

I think I found an issue: for develop Eq. 15 I used Eq. 3 which assume the exponent distributes Normally and I am not sure if it could be applied (see min 8:30 here)

joako: I added an update to modify the portfolio variance formulae. This isn't that important  aside from the fact that the portfolio variance now reduces to zero when one holds exactly the opposite amount of $W_1$ in $W_2$. So, if you don't follow it, just ignore it. It's really not that related to your original question.

I have been thinking about the blow up you mentioned: if $W_{2t}=-W_{1t}$ then both distributes as $N(0,t)$ again so I don't see why it would be a blown up? the processes $$S_t = S_0\exp\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t \pm \sigma W_{kt}$$ $k={1,\ 2}$ should have the same behaviors, right?

Suppose you put all of -1.0 W_1 into W_2 so you have 2 processes that are the exact opposite of each other. Then, in my mind, that portfolio has zero risk. Whatever W_1 does, W2 works exactly in the opposite direction so everything cancels out and there's nothing left. No risk and no return. But, if you take the standard portfolio variance formula, you can't make the variance zero without introducing  some trickery. How does one tell a portfolio variance formula that, when the 2 processes are opposite each other, then it should be zero.

Another way of saying is that you're formula needs to be such that $S_t = S_{0}$ for all $t$ because the stock price cannot increase or decrease. The portfolio is static and doesn't even return the risk free rate. It basically does not exist. Does that make sense ? Everything cancelled out.

joako: I'm essentially assuming that you have two processes that have the same value initially ( call it $S_{0}$ ) and process A moves in the exact opposite direction of process  B for all $t$ ( so they are perfectly negatively correlated ). Therefore, the two processes cancel each other and the $S_{0}$ can't change.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi Joako: chat is difficult for me because I keep strange hours. Think of this way.  Let $S_{01} = 10.00$ and $S_{02} = 20.00$. Assume an investor initially holds 10 shares of $S_{1}$ and 5 shares of $S_{2}$. Also, let $W_{2} = -1.0 \times W_{1}$. Then, as the GBM processes evolve and eventually  end, the investor will still have 10 shares of $S_{0,1}$ at 10 dollars per share  and 5 shares of $S_{2}$ at 20.00 per share. It's just as if time passed but nothing happened because the 2 processes cancelled each other out.

I have added some simulations that shows not just that what you are saying is not happening on GBM series (show $\rho[S_1,S_2]\neq -1$ as SextusEmpiricus says in his answer), but even worst, the correlation coefficients are approximating the unity as time passes: I don't know what to think right now, hope could take a look to see if we are talking about different things, or if I have a mistake in the simulations. Thanks beforehand.

Hi Joako: I'll print out the R code so I can go through it and try to understand it. Maybe this will help clarify the issue. Good idea. It just may take me some time because I'm not around much. I for sure will check it out and then comment.

Joako: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to work in price space or S space if you will. I'm also not much familar with matlab but I can see what you're doing for the most part. As far as the code, maybe it's easier to show it using the returns. So, log return from $t_{0}$ to $t_{1}  = (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(t_{1} -t_{0}) + \sigma W_{t_{1}}$.

joako: Let me know if looking at it from a log return perspective above helps at all. The second terms cancel and one is left with the same drift terms in both equations so yes, the return of each one won't be zero but they have to be identical.  My point is that having identical deterministic terms is pretty much what I said before in terms of : "Nothing Happens". The only difference is that now both assets can be getting the same deterministic rate of return that the local bank gives. But, other than that, one can still argue that "Pretty Much Nothing Happens".

What I don't understand if that the portfolio is made as $P_t = w_1S_1+w_2S_2$ with ${w_1,\ w_2}\geq 0$ weights such $w_1+w_2=1$, you try to see the variance of the log returns: these make sense when taking $R_p$, but makes no sense for taking $\sigma_p^2$, its components are the variances/covariances of ${S_1,\ S_2}$ and not the terms ${R_1,\ R_2}$. (...)

(...)  Even more, let name $x=\ln(w_1)+\ln(S_1)$ and  $y=\ln(w_2)+\ln(S_2)$ then the portfolio is $P_t=e^x+e^y$ and finding it log-return becomes $$\ln(P_r) = \ln(e^x+e^y) \approx \frac{x\ e^{\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}-y\ e^{\frac{y}{\ln(2)}}}{e^{\frac{x}{\ln(2)}}-e^{\frac{y}{\ln(2)}}} \neq \ln(e^x) +\ln(e^y) = x + y$$ so using the log returns for the variance part of the analysis makes little sense to me (correct me please if I am missing something). By the way, the approximation for splitting the logarithm of a sum I found it here

Hi Joako: I'm not clear what you are referring to by the variance of the log returns ? All I did was take your equation (comment was oct 15, 19:28) that expressed things in terms of S and re-wrote it so that things are expressed in terms of the difference of log returns.  I think it's clearer that way because the returns are then linear as  opposed to being exponentiated. To me, that equation makes things clearer as far as why the $W_1$ and $-1.0 \times W_1$ cancel out and one is left with the drift terms that don't mean much because they don't have any variation. i hope this makes sense.

I didn't address your other comments because I wanted to see if this makes sense yet. If it doesn't, I can try to explain it again maybe in a different way ?  The key point is that the two brownian motions cancel each other out and all that one is left with is 2 drift terms. There's no random variation in the return to the portfolio from $t_{0}$ to $t_1$.

I tried to remade all the analysis trying to found figures that explain what you said, and I found none, even when the simulations tell it do behaves as you told. I don't know what I did wrong, maybe just the classic figures for expected value and variance don't really work for GBM. Now I as lost as initially. I added the section at the end.

I do find at last a linearization when the portfolio, under strong assumptions, will behave as you mentioned. I run out of space so I added it as an answer here. Let me know if this is what you were thinking about please.

I am reviewing your code, and I don't find where yo make the GBM exponentiation so $S_i = S_0\exp\left(\sigma W_{t}+t\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)\right)$, as I am seeing it you made $S_i =S_0+\sigma W_{t}+t\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$ which is an Arithmetic Brownian Motion with a completely different behavior, in which I agree the noise cancellation happens naturally, since is linear $S_{N+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{N} S_k$, differently from the GBM where it is a compounded process $S_{N+1}=\Pi_{k=1}^{N} S_k$

I have realized on the last days huge conceptual mistakes in the sections of the question below the review of the portfolio returns, and I have fixed it accordingly and now it makes sense for me. Hope you could see it now and comment later.

Hi Joako: I don't have time to look at it now but could you be more specific as far as the location where the "review of the portfolio returns" is. This, I can read your fixes when I have time. Thanks.

Here the author of the question, extending the analysis since I got out of space.
Last update
The only reason I could find about why the efficient frontier works and the previous equation don't is like works for GBM series of similar sizes almost like a happy accident: Let say we have the portfolio of $\text{Eq. 25}$ then I could manipulate it as,
$$\begin{array}{r c l}
P_t &=& w_1S_{1t}+w_2S_{2t} = e^{\ln(w_1)}S_{1t}+e^{\ln(w_2)}S_{2t}\\
& = & e^{\ln(w_1S_{01})+\left(\mu_1-\frac{v_1^2}{2}\right)t+v_1W_{1t}}+e^{\ln(w_2S_{02})+\left(\mu_2-\frac{v_2^2}{2}\right)t+v_2W_{2t}}\\
& = & e^{X}+e^{Y} \equiv e^{Z}\tag{Eq. 33} \end{array}$$
Where I am representing the GBM asset $1$ as an exponent of a variable $X$ and the GBM asset $2$ as an exponent of a variable $Y$, and without loss of generality, I said the portfolio could be represented as an exponent of a variable $Z$: then I could find $Z$ as,
$$Z = \ln\left(e^X+e^Y\right) \tag{Eq. 34}$$
which is a wide known function in physics or neural networks named LogSumExp which is a smooth approximation of the maximum function: if I have that the magnitud of the variables $X$ and $Y$ are too different, let say $X\ll Y \vee Y\ll X$ (which I going to describe as $X\ll\gg Y$ since I don't know the math symbol for this), then the behavior will be:
$$Z \approx \max_{X\ll\gg Y}\left\{X;Y\right\}\tag{Eq. 35}$$
so the portfolio will just track the most important variable: note here it don't means the higher weight, since the initial values $S_{0i}$ also influence, and they are decoupled from the terms of each GBM exponent which also influence by themselves when $X$ would be notoriously different from $Y$.
But in the scenario $X\approx Y$ if I use a first order approximation (as I previously reviewed here), then the linear approximation of $Z$ will looks like:
$$Z = \ln\left(e^X+e^Y\right) \overset{\text{1st order}}{\approx} \ln(2)+ \frac{X+Y}{2}\tag{Eq. 36}$$
Then the portfolio would have the form:
$$P_t \approx 2\sqrt{w_1w_2S_{01}S_{02}}e^{\frac12\left(\mu_1+\mu_2-\frac{v_1^2}{2}-\frac{v_2^2}{2}\right)t+\frac{v_1}{2}W_{1t}+\frac{v_2}{2}W_{2t}} \tag{Eq. 37}$$
And here I think is not possible to recover the formula for the variance $\sigma_p$ neither the formula for $R_p$ from the lectures (please correct me if I am mistaken), but if I introduce the assumption of $v_1=v_2=v$ and $W_{2t}=-W_{1t}$ it is easy to see I will eliminate the randomness of the portfolio, as is mentioned by @SextusEmpiricus and @mlofton.
Notice in $\text{Eq. 37}$ that the drifts $\mu_i$ as the noises $v_iW_{it}$ are somehow linear, so even when don't perfectly fit the analysis of the efficient frontier, at least under the strong assumptions that leads to $\text{Eq. 37}$, the efficient frontier analysis is not completely out of line.
Which I don't know is if the size of the weights $w_i$ such it benefits earnings on $\text{Eq. 37}$ will coincide with the weights following the intuition of $\text{Eq. 31}$ (I believe they match since $X|_{t=0}\approx Y_{t=0}\iff w_1S_{01}\approx w_2S_{02}$), but what makes me dubious about the validity of this analysis, is that the weights determination is not coupled with the decision of what assets I should be picking (meaning here $w_i$ are not multiplying $v_iW_{it}$ as in $\sigma_p$ from the lectures), but instead, after choosing assets I would adjust the weights in order to fulfill some decoupled rule like the one of $\text{Eq. 31}$ or others (maybe $X\approx Y$ for some future time, guessing here).
I am also worried that the analysis using the classic Expected Value and Variance figures don't fit with the efficient frontier, neither with the simulations' results sometimes. I have checked them and still don't find any mistakes. Maybe the linearity mentioned in $\text{Eq. 36}$, added with the lost of correlation with time reviewed in the Update 2, is what leads to be continuously adjusting weights in real life portfolios, or instead the efficient frontier analysis would lost sense as one variable gains relevance and start fulfilling $\text{Eq. 35}$.
Hope you could comment.

Hi Joako: I don't have time to read your efficient frontier stuff right now but I'll try to read it on the train tonight. But, I decided to write R code which illustrates how the random return component cancels. I know you don't  use R but I'm adding the code as another addendum. I'm pretty certain that you can understand it and see how the random component cancels out and one is left with drift. I will print out the new version of the thread and read about Mr. Markowitz stuff.

joako: I put the code in another addendum. It didn't come out very nice. I'm not good with MathJax because I try to use it like it's latex. If you could edit my addendum to give me some revelations on how to make it look better, it's appreciated. You DEFINITELY know MathJax quite well. Thanks. As ugly as it is, I hope the code helps.

@mlofton Thanks you very much, I will study it (I am not familiar in R but I will learn it if needed - I learned several type of languages in the past so it shouldn't be an issue). By the way, I edited your answer so it looks like a code section, please check if I didn't messed it up

Thanks Joako. I'm still reading Harry's stuff. I have a couple of comments so far but I'll write them late tonight when I get home. Apologies for delay. I haven't been home much. As far as the code, I didn't exponentiate S anywhere because I'm just calculating the returns to investment, not the prices. The prices will increase because the drift is non-zero. But that's not the point. My point was that there is zero randomness in the process once one makes the second brownian motion $-1.0 \times W_1$. I'll get back to you later with a couple of other longer comments late tonight.

@mlofton Maybe I am mistaken but what I don't understand is why people use the returns as linear when they buy the assets and not the returns, I mean, the logarithm of a sum $\ln(e^x+e^y)$ is very different from the sum of the logarithms $\ln(e^x)+\ln(e^y)=x+y$... maybe I have a conceptual mistake

and don't worry about messing up code if you fixed it. I think you'll get or got the idea of what I'm doing which is the main reason I wrote it. There is no randomness in the trajectories once one brownian motion is the negative of the other.

joako: I gotta go but, if you buy the stock, then you get the return on the stock. So, after you get the return, say R, then you receive the increase in the price due to R ? Does that makes sense. I'm not sure what you mean by linear ? You can also calc, S * (1 + R) to do it in non logarithms, but it will still be S  so no increase.

joako: I'm still not sure what you mean by $ln(e^x + e^y)$ is very different from ...". The difference between log returns and arithmetic returns is that, with log returns, one is compounding the $n$ returns by multiplying them and then taking the nth root. With arithmetic returns, the compounding is done by calculating the mean return.  So, I'm not sure what you mean by what I quoted above. I'm gonna add another addendum because there's more space there. There are a couple of different issues that I will address that hopefully will clear some things up.

and thanks for cleaning up my attempt at putting R code. it looks much better and I see what you did.

Hi joako: After you read the addendum I added, here is the link to the variance drain paper I was referring to. I don't know how useful it will be as far as this thread is concerned but you may find it interesting regardless. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2027471

joako: I'm just gonna quickly add another addendum because I was thinking about it last night and it's not hard to show ( atleast not rigorously ) that arithmetic returns imply that price changes ( and consequently arithmetic returns ) follow BM. So, I'm adding it on just you can see the inconsistency more clearly. Also, it's for myself so that my comments are clearer since I kind of waved my hands about that in the previous addendum. All the best if we don't end up communicating further.
